# Implement a tag system in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I'd like to implement a tag system to a SugarCRM that has the following characteristics:

1. User can create any new tag just by writing the new tag into the tag field
2. Existing tags are suggested for user to choose, in order to avoid having similar tags (e.g. if user tried to enter "sugar" as tag, it should be suggested for them to choose "SugarCRM")
3. Search by tag should result only records that have that tag, but not records that have that tag as a keyword in title or description fields
4. All record in all modules should have a tag field
5. It would be nice if a search by tag could be made throughout all modules

Does anyone know if there is already some implementation for this?

Comment: If you are still looking for it, or want to switch to better add-on, take a look at https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/tagme

Answer (score 2):

There are several on SugarForge. I've used SugarTAGS from CARRENET (http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/sugartags/) as a starting point before.